# How to point to the index.html in WebpackDevServer config?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a `build` folder where the bundle is put when compiled. This folder is in `.gitignore` and is not commited to git repo.

I need a `index.html` file which is by default put in `build` folder as well.

Can I put `index.html` into another folder which is inside git repo and point to this as the entry point?

Comment: Yes! How do you generate `index.html`

Comment: Might be helpful https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/536#issuecomment-59530883